# how to remove reference from array of references in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a comment schema with children array that contains references to other comments. When I delete one comment, I want a command to delete the reference to it in it's parent comment. So far I have this but it's not working. How do I do it correctly?

SCHEMA:

```
var CommentSchema = Schema({
    body: {type: String},
    chapterId: {type: RK, ref: 'Chapter'},
    by: {type: RK, ref: 'User'},
    children: [{
        type: RK,
        ref: 'Comment'

     }]
}, {timestamps: true});

CommentSchema.pre('remove', function(next){

    this.model('CommentSchema').remove({children:this._id}, next);
})
```

command:

```
Comment.findByIdAndUpdate(parent, {$pull:{children:{_id: mainid}}})
```

Why doesnt this work??^^^^
I don't know how else to do it.
parent is the id of the parent comment. I verified it's valid. mainid is the id of the comment being deleted, which the parent contains in its ref array, also valid.

Comment: I think your problem is your calling 'findByIdAndUpdate' but expecting to arrive at the function that handles your 'pre - remove' 

So the command you're calling is 'findByIdAndUpdate' so I think the 'pre' should be for [link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) findOneAndUpdate. And you should remove all comments with the id's in 'children' array whit in your new 'pre':

schema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function (next) {
    //remove all children from schema
});

Comment: i simply did an update to remove the id from the childen array. then removed the child completely. worked fine like that. tho seems like findbyidandupdate just doesnt work properly. doing the precondition didn't work either.